# MySQL: Windows ou Linux?

Tags: mysql, linux, windows

Qual deles tem melhor desempenho para servidor dedicado com MySQL considerando diversos cálculos complexos em Stored Procedure e Functions?

Comment: Esse tipo de resposta pode ser muito variável e muito dependente de opiniões, tendo em vista que você pode mudar muito o ambiente de uma resposta para outra e ter resultados muito diferentes por causa disso...

Comment: Esta pergunta não tem uma resposta. Se você tiver servidores com exatamente o mesmo hardware rodando windows e linux você terá resultados muito parecidos.

Comment: Eu não vejo nada de errado com essa pergunta, apenas falta uma definição de métricas para se fazer as devidas comparações, o rapaz procura por algo tipo benchmark, apesar dos apesares é possível usar "métricas" nessa pergunta, reformular para uma única situação bem definida e por fim fazer as análises dos resultados, seria uma verdade para aquela situação.

Comment: @mcardoso procure reformular a pergunta para algo mais definido passei um link na minha resposta da uma olhada ali o rapaz faz uma definição do ambiente e mostrou os resultados para aquela situação, acho válido

Answer (score 3):

Há **vantagens em utilizar o `Linux`** para este propósito, como outros poderão dizer, mas de um ponto de vista sobre `performance`, para muitas aplicações você não verá muita diferença.

Enquanto `Linux` seria **minha recomendação**, se você é mais familiar com o WIndows e não tem muita experiência como `sysadmin Linux`, escolha o Windows. Ter conhecimento de consertar certas coisas faz-o ganhar em tempo e consequentemente em **dinheiro** já que, repetindo, entre ambos, não haverá muita diferença.

Mas observe, `Windows` é mais lento ao criar arquivos. 40 tabelas `InnoDB` envolvem 40 ou 80 criações de arquivo.

Uma boa prática no MySQL seria criar as tabelas de uma vez e não criar/deletar tabelas frequentemente. Se sua aplicação foi desenhada para criar/deletar VÁRIAS tabelas, o `Linux` é com certeza o mais indicado.

Se boa parte do tempo sua aplicação utiliza tabelas temporárias, o MySQL 5.7 obteve significantes mudanças na performance (em `ambos os OS`) nesta área.

**Outra coisa**, se o servidor dedicado em questão for servir outro tipo de conteúdo (exemplo: web/PHP), minha recomendação será sucinta em escolher o **Linux** ao invés do **Windows**.

Comment: `Mas observe, Windows é mais lento ao criar arquivos. 40 tabelas InnoDB envolvem 40 ou 80 criações de arquivo.`

Você tem uma fonte que comprove isso?

Comment: Fonte: `eu mesmo`  =D. Trabalhei 7 anos com dedicados Windows e Linux. Windows era quase sempre um sofrimento. Linux zipa e descompacta arquivos num piscar de olhos. Multiplos arquivos, inclusive. **Outra fonte**: http://www.pcworld.com/article/230527/ubuntu_linux_day_16_ext4_vs_ntfs.html

Comment: O que rege a performance na criação e manipulação de arquivos no HDD é, inclusive, o `file system`.

Answer (score 2):

Muito difícil de responder essa questão no quesito performance, uma vez que tudo é relativo, teríamos que tentar simular um ambiente igual para ambos e testar vários aspectos, exemplo:

- O mesmo **hardware**, hardware de ponta pode acabar beneficiando uma plataforma e hardware de requisitos mínimos outra na questão custo benefício para bancos pequenos poucas tabelas etc, ou bancos gigantes tabelas parrudas,
- As consultas rodando **local** ou **rede**, ai já poderíamos ter 1 ponto para cada, e este tipo de teste pode ficar estranho porque vão dizer local é o que conta e dar ponto para um, mas o banco de dados geralmente é consultado por clientes em rede e a performance acaba sendo mensurado pelos demais processos envolvidos e não diretamente o software MySql.
- Seria válido fazer uma **customização**? Nesse requisito não sei até que ponto seria justo tanto para um quanto para outro, manter as melhores configurações para a plataforma windows e usar esses parametros em linux? ou vise-versa? Qualquer configuração seria injusto porque irá acabar beneficiando um ou outro.
- Usaríamos **máximos ou mínimos** valores a respeito de memórias e buffers, pois acredite, pode dar melhor performance para um em bancos pequenos e dar outra quando for bancos muito grande.

Então se usarmos todas as possibilidades teríamos 1 vencedor para cada situação/métricas usadas.

Segue um exemplo http://informationideas.com/news/2008/05/01/mysql-on-windows-vs-linux/

Comment: Agora se falarmos em segurança seria mais facil responder... e performance só não vou falar linux porque me falta os dados que comprovem...rsrsrsr